# How to check if an integer includes a certain number in c#

Tags: c#, numbers, integer, int

Is there a way I can check Integers if they contain a certain number in C#?

> For example:
>
> I want to check for 7.  When I enter 17, the code will return 1.  When I enter 28, the code will return 0.

Thank You

Comment: `int result = number.ToString().Contains("7") ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Question is off-topic for stackoverflow. You should describe the problem and show *what has been done so far to solve it*.

Comment: `variables`? What type? basic types? array/list/dictionary? complex userdefined objects?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int number = 17;
int digit = 7;
bool result = number.ToString().Contains(digit.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

We can find it without converting the number to a string, by using a while loop.

> This way is not recommended. But it will help some people who are new
> to coding.

Suppose your number is "number"  and the "digit" is a certain number which you want to check is included in "number", in this case digit is 7 and the number is 17,

```
public bool includesInteger(int number, int digit)
{
  while(number > 0)
  {
      if (number % 10 == digit) return true;
      number /= 10;
  }
 return false; 
}
```

The logic is very simple. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a string, then use `String.Contains`:

```
int i = 17;
int j = 28
int k = 7;

bool a = i.ToString().Contains(k.ToString());
bool b = j.ToString().Contains(k.ToString());
```